# Absolute URL .. 400 BAD Request

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty

I am currently running a jetty web server in my application. One of the clients is calling my this using HttpPost.

Sometimes it works and sometimes he gets a HTTP 400 BAD Request.

These are the logs

```
About to connect() to 10.184.209.142 port 8080 
Trying 10.184.209.142... 
Connected to 10.184.209.142 (10.184.209.142) port 8080 
POST /CSCIntegration HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: CSC Test
Host: 10.184.209.142:8080
Accept: */*
From: anonymous@unknown.com
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 440
```

If I am running the same using a Junit I do not see any issues.

Is it because of the missing trailing slash in HttpPost??
Is this error due to [jetty issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1533)??

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because of the missing trailing slash in HttpPost?? Is this error due to jetty issue??

Possibly.  It depends on two things:

- Whether you are using an old version of Jetty that doesn't have that issue fixed.  If you read the [linked bugzilla entry](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=396566), the bug was fixed over a year ago.
- Whether the client is using URLs with missing trailing slashes.

> If I am running the same using a Junit I do not see any issues.

It is unclear what you are saying.

- If you are saying that you can reproduce the problem by hand but not with a JUnit test (that was *designed* to reproduce this), check you are using the same version of Jetty in your tests and in your production system.  Then check for differences in configuration.
- If you are simply saying that your JUnit tests don't cover this problem, then the solution is obvious.  Write a new test that *does* cover it!

If none of that helps, then you should consider attaching a debugger to your production server (ouch!) to figure out what is actually happening.

Comment: currently I am using jetty-7.4.4.v20110707 and this bug was fixed in the later version of jetty. The way I have written the Junit is by starting the jetty server (the same code that is being used in prod) and then calling it locally on port 8080 as follows:

Comment: StringEntity se = new StringEntity("data")     
    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml"));
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8888/CSCIntegration");
    post.setEntity(se);
    post.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    response = client.execute(post);

Comment: When running this way using Jetty -7.4.4 I don't see any issues when calling it with URL localhost:8888/CSCIntegration. So I am kind of not sure if this is really because of trailing slash at the end of URL.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the bug.  As I read it, it is about URLs that have a completely empty path ... not a non-empty path that doesn't end with a slash.  1) Your test-case is not testing the condition in which the bug would manifest.  2) Unless you actually attempt to reproduce the problem with a URL that is equivalent to what the customer is using AND using the same version of Jetty, you are probably wasting your time.  Create a custom JUnit test that does that!